# Perl 5.16.3.1 win32 Devel::REPL module-build-tiny fails to install

Tags: perl, winapi

I am using strawberry Perl win32 version 5.16.3.1 on Windows 7 and am trying to install the Devel::REPL module which seems to use module-build-tiny and both fail. From the install I get:

```
----     ETHER/Devel-REPL-1.003025.tar.gz     ---
    Module::Build::Tiny [build_requires]
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running install for module 'Module::Build::Tiny'
...

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/simple.t            (Wstat: 1280 Tests: 21 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 5
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=3, Tests=22, 14 wallclock secs ( 0.13 usr +  0.06 sys =  0.19 CPU)
Result: FAIL
  LEONT/Module-Build-Tiny-0.028.tar.gz
  C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe ./Build test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports LEONT/Module-Build-Tiny-0.028.tar.gz
Running Build install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Module::Build::Tiny'.
Failed during this command:
 LEONT/Module-Build-Tiny-0.028.tar.gz         : make_test NO
```

I tried running force but it still fails at the first simple.t test - a dialog opens to say that Perl has stopped running.

Thoughts on what I need to do to get this to work? Thanks.

Comment: Partially fixed by installing B::Utils, however, now Data::Dump::Streamer is the pre-requisite that fails, and it is failing all tests but I don't see a particular pre-requisite that is causing th e issue.

Comment: Data::Dump::Streamer was missing ExtUtils::Depends and Module::Build, fixing those did not fix the issue though. Still fails all tests.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Conflict with MinGW which was in the path prior to Strawberry's MinGW environment. Changed the path order and it works fine now.